# How do I interpret aide.log change summary

Tags: linux, security, aide

In the Changed files section of /var/log/aide/aide.log there are prefixes on each line starting with f or d.  These signify what aspects of the file has changed, but I can't seem to track down what they mean.  (Obviously I could look at the detailed data for the file further down the log file, but a definitive reference for the summary lines is important for grepping.)

Here are some examples:

```
f >.p.. mci.CA. .: /etc/passwd-
d =.... mc.. .. .: /bin
f =.... mci.C.. .: /bin/ip
d =.... mc.n A. .: /u1/home
```

Comment: _file_ and _directory_ ?

Comment: Post edited with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is detailed in the [`aide.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/aide.conf) manual page, reproduced here for completeness, and is a configurable attribute of the generated reports:

> `summarize_changes`
>
> > Whether to summarize changes in the added, removed and changed files
> >     sections of the report or not. Valid values are yes,true,no and false.
> >     The default is not to summarize the changes.
> >
> > The general format is like the string YlZbpugamcinCAXS, where *Y* is
> >     replaced by the file-type (**f** for a regular file, **d** for a directory, **L**
> >     for a symbolic link, **D** for a character device, **B** for a block device, **F**
> >     for a FIFO, **s** for a unix socket and **?** otherwise).
> >
> > The *Z* is replaced as follows: A **=** means that the size has not changed,
> >     a **<** reports a shrinked size and a **>** reports a grown size.
> >
> > The  other letters in the string are the actual letters that will be
> >     output if the associated attribute for the item has been changed or a
> >     "**.**" for no change, a "**+**" if the attribute has been added, a "**-**" if it
> >     has been removed, a "**:**" if the attribute is listed in ignore_list or a
> >     " " if the attribute has not been checked. The exceptions to this are:
> >     (1)  a newly created  file replaces each letter with a "**+**", and (2)
> >     a removed file replaces each letter with a "**-**".
> >
> > The attribute that is associated with each letter is as follows:
> >
> > - A **`l`** means that the link name has changed.
> > - A **`b`** means that the block count has changed.
> > - A **`p`** means that the permissions have changed.
> > - An **`u`** means that the uid has changed.
> > - A **`g`** means that the gid has changed.
> > - An **`a`** means that the access time has changed.
> > - A **`m`** means that the modification time has changed.
> > - A **`c`** means that the change time has changed.
> > - An **`i`** means that the inode has changed.
> > - A **`n`** means that the link count has changed.
> > - A **`C`** means that one or more checksums have changed.
> > - A **`A`** means that the access control list has changed.
> > - A **`X`** means that the extended attributes have changed.
> > - A **`S`** means that the SELinux attributes have changed.